# How to run Display Settings from the CLI virtual terminal?

Tags: 14.04, 64-bit

How to run  **Display Settings** from **CLI virtual terminal** (`Ctrl`+`Alt`+`F1`) ?

[image]

Comment: Are you actually starting an X session on VT1? or are you asking about launching GUI applications from the CLI virtual terminal?

Comment: launching GUI applications from the CLI virtual terminal, yes

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must be referring to:

```
gnome-control-center display
```

You can find the command in the `.desktop` file:

```
gnome-display-panel.desktop
```

This `.desktop` file is to be found in `/usr/share/applications`

Comment: @begueradj wait, from Ctrl+Alt+F1 ?? You mean Ctrl+Alt+T I guess? You won't run any GUI application from Ctrl+Alt+F1

Comment: Although **if** there is a desktop session already running, then you should be able to open the display settings on **that** from the VT by prepending the command with the appropriate `DISPLAY` variable e.g. `DISPLAY=:0 unity-control-center display`

Comment: thank you very much. I will upvote tomorrow for reasons you may guess as an experienced member :)

Comment: @steeldriver, you are right, but apparently, OP meant a terminal window :)

Comment: @begueradj You make me curious :)

Comment: @JacobVlijm because I reached my upvoting limit :)

Comment: @begueradj WOW, I didn't even know there *was* a "ceiling" :)

Comment: @JacobVlijm there is :) it is 30 per day. At least for a user with my reputation :) There is a badge about it too

Comment: @begueradj I should try to hit the limit some day :)

Answer (score 0):

For Cinnamon desktop environment (Like for Linux Mint or Ubuntu with Cinnamon DE):

```
cinnamon-settings display
```

Has saved me a lot of times since my second monitor won't start up from sleep until I open the Display Settings.

I bind this to 'pause'-button in the Keyboard Shortcuts